# Rxjs switchMap -> concatMap -> toArray not comleted toArray

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

```
const allAnimatedElement$ = ($val: JQuery) => from($val).pipe(
  map(val => $(val)),
  concatMap($val => animateElement$($val)),
  toArray(),
  tap(val => console.log(`all: ${val}`)),
)

const animateDescription$ = nonStopedStream$.pipe(
  map(val => $('return array')),
  // switchMap($val => allAnimatedElement$($val)),
  switchMap($val => from($val).pipe(finalize(() => console.log('end arr')))),
  map(val => $(val)),
  concatMap($val => animateElement$($val)),
  toArray(),
  tap(val => console.log(`all: ${val}`)),,
);

const animateElement$ = ($element: JQuery): Observable<JQuery> =>
  new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
    const initialWidth = $element.width();

    $element.css({ width: 0, opacity: 1 }).velocity(
      { width: initialWidth },
      {
        duration: 1000,
        complete() {
          observer.next($element);
          observer.complete();
        },
      }
    );
  });
```

First switchMap perform as expected (see all message), but second - don't see all message. How can fix that in the second switchMap?

Eventually, I want that array divide on previous and current elements, then when nonstop emit new values, asynchronously animate current array, and restore previous array to initial position.

I just study rxjs and want to write a slider for learning.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `toArray` emits only when the source Observable completes.

Comment: @martin, thanks, is there a way to switch the flow to an internal observable and find out when it will end?

Comment: @Kazus just stumbled over the same issue. Have you found a solution to that problem / can you still remember? :P

Comment: @MichaelKargl sorry for late response, I've changed the code and used `buffer`:

```lang-js
const animateDescription$ = slideIndex$
  .pipe(
    map(val => data.$descriptions.eq(val).find('.rx-animation-unit')),
    switchMap($next => animateAllElements$($next)),
    buffer(slideIndex$),
    filter(val => !!val.length),
    flatMap($prev => restoreElements$($prev))
  )
```